# Sorting output of "*" wildcard for cd/ln command

Tags: bash, scripting

Im creating a tiny script to help symlinking some files to a specific directory (in this case its from a cloned repo to the themes folder on the host os (in this case macos)), Anyways the problem is that blender creates new folders for managing the preferences for each version as such

```
3.1
└ Config
└ Scripts
└ Startup

3.2
└ Config
└ Scripts
└ Startup
```

. and so on

I figured out that i can just use the "*" wildcard to represent these but i need a way to select the folder with the highest numerical value for the ln command

If its any help the command i figured out so far is just

```
ln -sf /'path to theme file' '.../'directory with highest numerical value'/.../interface-theme')
```

Comment: should something like `3.1`, `3.2`, `3.11` sort in that order, and not e.g. `3.1`, `3.11`, `3.2`?

Comment: It should indeed sort through as 3.1 > 3.11 > 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
() {
  ln -sf -- /'path to theme file' $argv[-1]/interface-theme
} '.../'*'/...(/n)
```

Where the `n` glob qualifier enables `numericglobsort` (where `3.10` sorts after `3.9` instead of between `3.1` and `3.2`) for that one glob and `/` restricts the glob to files of type *directory* (replace with `-/` to also consider symlinks to directories; note that the `*` itself does follow symlinks). We pass that ordered list of directories to an anonymous function where we use the last argument (`$argv[-1]`) in the `ln` command.

Alternatively, using the `e` glob qualifier to append the link name and `[-1]` to select the last glob expansion:

```
ln -sf -- /'path to theme file' '.../'*'/...(/n[-1]e[REPLY+=/interface-theme])
```

With `bash` (the GNU shell) 4.4 or newer and GNU utilities, you can do something approaching with:

```
print0() {
  (( $# == 0 )) || printf '%s\0' "$@"
}
readarray -td '' dirs < <(
  shopt -s nullglob
  print0 '.../'*'/...'/ |
    sort -zrV
) &&
  (( ${#dirs[@]} )) &&
  ln -sf -- /'path to theme file' "${dirs[1]}"interface-theme
```

The `-V` (aka `--version-sort`) does a sorting similar to that of `zsh`'s `n` glob qualifier. `*/` is similar to `zsh`'s `*(-/)` (selects directories and symlinks to directories) except that a `/` is appended.

Or assuming `zsh` is available, you could just do:

```
zsh -c '
  ln -sf -- /"path to theme file" ".../"*"/...(/n[-1]e[REPLY+=/interface-theme])'
```

Comment: This does work perfectly fine though i would like to be able to do this in sh or bash as i want the script to be able to work on linux hosts too

Comment: @Madoka, zsh, like bash has been around for over 30 years and ported to all Unix-like systems. It's packaged by all main GNU/Linux distributions and has been so long  before MacOS/X (where zsh is installed by default) even existed assuming that's the OS you had in mind when you wrote *"also"*. There's no equivalent for sh/bash, you could do something similar with bash (the GNU shell) and GNU utilities, though a lot more painfully.

Comment: Hmm fair enough, i wanted to use sh because i think thats the best practive with Unix systems and atleast every distro i know of ships with bash by default but i suppose just having zsh for the linux script wouldnt be a bad idea either. Thank you for your help! 
Also id appreciate if you could post a code snippet for how to do this in bash too if thats not too much work